# Show entropy values in J48 trees WEKA

Tags: weka, decision-tree, entropy, j48

I am quite new to Weka but what I am trying to do is to print the Entropy values for each split in my J48 trees. 
The command line I am using to train the tree is:

```
java -classpath CLASSPATH:weka.jar weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -C 0.25 -M 2 -t Matrix70.arff -d 70.model -S ENTROPY
```

but I have an error message:

```
Weka exception: Illegal options: ENTROPY
```

Do you know how to get ENTROPY values?

Thanks